# clear hikashop cart session in varibile time

Tags: joomla-3.x, session, hikashop

how clear hikashop cart session in every 5 miunuets?
when user add item in cart, if under 5 minutes , do not payment process , empty cart for user .
some code of hikashop  cart.php

```
function addToCartFromFields(&$entriesData,&$fields){
    $this->resetCart(false);
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    $productsToAdd = array();
    $coupons = array();
    foreach($entriesData as $entryData){
        foreach(get_object_vars($entryData) as $namekey=>$value){
            foreach($fields as $field){
                if($field->field_namekey == $namekey){
                    $ok = false;
                    if(!empty($field->field_options) && !is_array($field->field_options))
                        $field->field_options = hikashop_unserialize($field->field_options);
                    if(!empty($field->field_options['product_id'])){
                        if(is_numeric($value) && is_numeric($field->field_options['product_value'])){
                            if( $value === $field->field_options['product_value'] ){
                                $ok = true;
                            }
                        }elseif(is_string($value) && !empty($field->field_options['product_value']) && is_array($field->field_options['product_value']) && in_array($value,$field->field_options['product_value'])){
                            $ok = true;
                        }elseif($value == $field->field_options['product_value']){
                            $ok = true;
                        }

                        if($ok){
                            $id = $field->field_options['product_id'];
                            if(empty($productsToAdd[$id])){
                                $productsToAdd[$id]=1;
                            }else{
                                $productsToAdd[$id]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($field->field_type=='coupon' && !empty($field->coupon[$value])){
                        $coupons[] = $field->coupon[$value];
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the configuration options (version 3 of Hikashop):

Go to backend:

Hikashop -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced Settings

[image: Configure cart retaining period]

Comment: hikashop support descript for "cart retaining period" :
It's normal. The cart retaining period and frequency are done when you access the backend of the shop.
The point is to clear the carts once in a while. So that you have about a few weeks or months of carts in the database and not that it grows indefinitely.
Even if you set it to 5 minutes, it won't clear the carts every five minutes.